# Создание Бота для продажи VPN конфигов на базе Wire Guard

Tags: python, python-3.x, node.js

всем привет!

случилась такая проблема что нигде не могу найти как написать ПО (скрипт) для автоматической подачи конфигураций к боту на базе Wire Guard.

что нужно сделать->
1- VDS сервер написать на нем скрипт для того что бы после (успешной) оплаты он отправлял конфигурацию (Ключ) пользователю (Боту).

2- что бы была активная подписка а именно, купил юзер на 1 месяц - после 1 месяца что бы подписка истекла.

P.S Код написать не прошу, дайте люди добрую инфу где, как, и на чем мне это написать, что изучить...

Спасибо :)